# LINEST function in excel vba

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba, trendlines

I am trying to figure out the 2 order equation (Y = ax^2 + bx + c) for a set of data values. When I use the inbuilt function in excel

```
=LINEST(C2533:C2537,B2533:B2537^{1,2})
```

I get the following result for the datas I have choosen

```
3.08414E-09 -0.00041244 7.351136804
```

**But when I try the same in Excel VBA code the answers do not co-relate can any one tell me what should the modification in code?**

```
Set RangeM = ("C2533:C2537")  -->Y axis
Set RangeF = ("B2533:B2537") --> Xaxis
Mpolynomials = Application.WorksheetFunction.LinEst(RangeM, RangeF, True, True)
```

- :     Mpolynomials(1) :  : Variant(1 to 2) 
    :     Mpolynomials(1,1) : -2.88227749032385E-04 : Variant/Double 
    :     Mpolynomials(1,2) : 6.10919130371322 : Variant/Double
- :     Mpolynomials(2) :  : Variant(1 to 2) 
    :     Mpolynomials(2,1) : 2.49037160577299E-06 : Variant/Double 
    :     Mpolynomials(2,2) : 0.050203149944234 : Variant/Double
- :     Mpolynomials(3) :  : Variant(1 to 2) 
    :     Mpolynomials(3,1) : 0.999776086266518 : Variant/Double 
    :     Mpolynomials(3,2) : 9.34516966780855E-03 : Variant/Double
- :     Mpolynomials(4) :  : Variant(1 to 2) 
    :     Mpolynomials(4,1) : 13395.0169654829 : Variant/Double 
    :     Mpolynomials(4,2) : 3 : Variant/Double
- :     Mpolynomials(5) :  : Variant(1 to 2) 
    :     Mpolynomials(5,1) : 1.16981624866201 : Variant/Double 
    :     Mpolynomials(5,2) : 2.61996588360387E-04 : Variant/Double

Answer (score 1):

I did some browsing and obtained the way to get the polynomials for the second order equation

Mpolynomials = Application.WorksheetFunction.LinEst(RangeM, Application.Power(RangeF, Array(1, 2)))

Here Mpolynomials is a Variant